# Is are the DDR RAM slot directly connected to the cpu address bus?

Tags: memory, cpu

Are the DDR RAM slots directly connected to the CPU address bus? Or they connected to the external MMC (memory management controller)?

Comment: Your motherboard model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the motherboard,chipset, and CPU.

Sometimes the memory is directly connected to the CPU, and sometimes there is a Northbridge chipset chip that acts as go between.

Most of the newer CPUs interact directly with the memory, or if they do have a controller it is built into the CPU.